# OpenCL Installation on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, cuda, opencl

i have a problem to which i want a solution and fast....any help is appreciated.

I have a laptop with **ubuntu10.04** and **Nvidia 8400M GS** graphics card. I recently started some work on OpenCL and wanted to run it on my laptop's GPU...but i ran into many problems the day I started.

I downloaded the latest drivers and sdk's needed for running OpenCL on an Nvidia GPU. I have installed
1. NVIDIA-Linux-x86-260.19.36 driver
2. devdriver-3.2-linux-32-260.19.26 driver
3. cudatoolkit_3.2.16_linux_32_ubuntu10.04 CUDA Toolkit
4. gpucomputingsdk-3.2.16-linux GPU SDK

I set the PATH and the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variables as was indicated after the installation process of the cuda toolkit. After that i went to the *NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/OpenCL* directory and typed *sudo make* (as was given [here](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/2_3/opencl/sdk/docs/release_notes_opencl.txt)). But i get the error

```
   ‘glXGetCurrentContext’ was not declared in this scope
```

I can't understand what the problem is. Have I missed something to install or is there some problem with the MakeFile and I have to change some options in there?

Also after this step, how am I supposed to link run an OpenCL program code using this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ok after doind some more research i found that i had to install _libglew1.5-dev libglu1-mesa-dev_ and i did so and the error vanished. :)

Comment: But another one popped up....now it shows   _/usr/bin/ld:cannot find -lGL_  Please somone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed `libgl1-mesa-dev`?

These packages provide this file:
http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libgl.so&mode=exactfilename&suite=lucid&arch=any

Comment: hmmm....i read many places that there was something like _nvidia-current_. I didn't have that on my system. Is there a way ti install it through apt-get??\

Comment: `apt-get install nvidia-current`. But you should check if you get a driver version that is reasonable up to date with this pacakge. See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps kludgy, but I just static link in my build files to the libraries and includes. There are now at least 3 (Intel, AMD, NVIDIA) OpenCL implementations to juggle.